# Google play APK - You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned.

Tags: eclipse, apk, construct

I've created a web-browser using construct 2 application and once i have finished it and had an executable .apk file, i tried to upload it to google play but it always gives me this error, "You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a zip align tool on your APK and upload it again."
Could someone tell me how to fix this?
PS: i also have bought eclipse software.
thanks

Comment: PS: i have downloaded Android Studio too